# Desenvolver para windows ce/mobile no visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, windows-ce, smartdevice

Já fiz diversas pesquisas na web para encontrar algum solução para o meu problema, mas, todos os tutoriais (artigos) que eu encontrei, foram falhos para a minha solução.

**MEU CASO**

Atualmente eu possuo diversos projetos smart device project (Device Application), para windows mobile 6 e windows ce, desenvolvidos na IDE Visual Studio 2008 R2 (.NET Compact Framework 3.5)

Além desse projeto também possuo diversos outros: WebService Application(asmx), WCF, Web Application, Windows Application, ...
Todos eles antigamente eram desenvolvidos no Visual Studio 2008. Esses eu conseguir migrá-los para o Visual Studio 2013. Mas, o citado anteriormente eu não consegui.

**MEU PROBLEMA**

Migrar o projeto smart device para windows mobile 6 do visual studio 2008 para o visual studio 2013.
O visual studio 2013, não consegui abrir o projeto, e o mesmo não apresenta a opção de smartdevice quando na criação de um novo projeto.

No visual studio 2008 já tem nativo a opção para projeto smartdevice.
No visual studio 2013 não possui está opção. Possui a categoria para projetos Windows Phone, mas, não possui um para windows mobile 6.

Então, o que eu quero realmente é uma opção no visual studio 2013 para criar projetos para windows mobile 6.

*Obs.: Consegui encontrar um SDK que é para projetos windows mobile 8, mas eu preciso para windows mobile 6 e windows ce também.

Comment: E o seu problema é? Você só escreveu que tem um problema. Todos temos vários. Detalhe o seu problema, mensagem de erro, situação, etc.

Comment: Como mencionado em: "Mas, o citado anteriormente eu não consegui". O que diz, que eu consegui não consegui migrar o projeto do visual studio 2008 para o 2013, projeto esse que é o para smart device para windows mobile 6. Irei fazer uma alteração no contexto para ficar mais clara.

Comment: E o erro exibido foi?

Comment: Fiz, mais alterações no escopo da pergunta. Espero que assim ela esteja mais objetiva. Com isso, a liberação da mesma, pois, estou precisando de uma solução para a mesma.

Comment: @DiegoMoreno não é possível usar o VS 2013 para isso. O suporte ao .net compact depende de uma combinação do OS, da versão do .net compact e do VS correspondente. Para esse projeto em específico terá que continuar a usar o VS2008 e devido ao fato de ser uma tecnologia antiga pouco provável que a microsoft ainda dê suporte a ela.

Comment: Veja este cenário [aqui](http://csharp-devs.blogspot.de/2014/04/windows-ce-development-with-vs2013.html). Pode ser que te auxilie.

Answer (score 2):

Não dá para fazer essa migração. Já passei pelo mesmo problema e a única solução que tive foi manter as duas versões do Visual Studio e alternar entre ambas.

Encontrei [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241978/developing-net-compact-framework-apps-in-post-2008-visual-studio/24247918#24247918) a uma questão parecida no stackoverflow-en.

Parece existir uma forma de configurar o VS2012 para que funcione com o Windows CE 6/7...mas para o VS2013 não encontrei nada:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205155928/http://geekswithblogs.net/WernerWillemsens/archive/2013/09/13/building-windows-ce-6-or-7-smart-device-application-with.aspx)

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201024012544/http://geekswithblogs.net/WernerWillemsens/archive/2013/09/13/154016.aspx)

Se eu fosse a ti não arriscava, e mantinha as duas versões do VS.

Answer (score 1):

No Visual Studio 2013 você não irá conseguir desenvolver para Windows Mobile 6, apenas para 8 em diante.
Fique no Visual Studio 2005 ou 2008 para continuar com o seu projeto. Acredito que não terá problemas ou empecilhos quanto a isso. Espero ter ajudado.